# How to add auto increment number on click Add row button in interactive grid Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, grid, report, oracle-apex, interactive

I am using interactive grid in Oracle Apex. I want to add auto increment number on click on Add Row button.

Whenever I click on "Add row", it will automatically add a sequence number.

Answer (score 1):

- create a sequence (let's call it `p_seq`) as

  ```
  create sequence p_seq;
  ```
- open column's properties
- go to "Default" section
- set type to "PL/SQL Function Body"
- put this in there:

  ```
  return p_seq.nextval;
  ```
- run the page